# HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP - Tomcat 7 - JDK and JRE - Ubuntu 14

Tags: java, jsp, ubuntu, tomcat7

I am trying to run some code on Tomcat 7 on Ubuntu Server 14.04 - 64 bit (setup at the bottom). When I try and load the page or refresh I get either error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.William2.web.deals_jsp
```

Or

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:
```

I put the code on this virtual machine for you to see the error :)
`http://128.199.226.137:8080/William2/web/index.jsp`

I have installed tomcat using:

```
sudo apt-get install Tomcat 7
```

JDK and JRE installed via :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Here is my code:

```
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONValue"%>
<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
    import="org.json.JSONArray,org.json.JSONException"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="org.json.JSONArray"%>
<%@ page language="java" %>

<%@page import="java.util.StringTokenizer"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileReader"%>
<%@page import="java.io.InputStreamReader"%>
<%@page import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/ico/favicon.ico">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Daily Deals</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/core.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $('span.productCountdown').each(function (index, element) {
                //var futureMoment = moment($(element).text());

                setInterval(function () {
                    var secondsLeftUntilFuture = futureMoment.diff(moment()) / 1000,
                        date = new Date(null);

                    date.setSeconds(secondsLeftUntilFuture);
                    $(element).text(date.getUTCHours() + ':' + date.getUTCMinutes() + ':' +  date.getUTCSeconds());
                }, 1000)
                                //;
            });


        });
    </script>
</head>
  <body>

       <%!
String name="",id="",name1="",id1="";      
%>

 <%
            FileReader f=new FileReader("C:/product/iphone.json");
            String ss[]=new String[17];
            int n=0;


            BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(f);
            String s;
            String nn;

            while((nn =bf.readLine())!=null )
                                       {
                ss[n]=nn;

                n++;
            }
            String delim=":";
            StringTokenizer tk2=new StringTokenizer(ss[1],":", true);
             StringTokenizer tk3=new StringTokenizer(ss[7],":", true);
         StringTokenizer tk4=new StringTokenizer(ss[8],":", true);
          StringTokenizer tk5=new StringTokenizer(ss[14],":", true);
          boolean expectDelim = false;

           //  String delim=":";

            while (tk2.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = tk2.nextToken();

    if (delim.equals(token)) {
         if (expectDelim) {
            expectDelim = false;
            continue;
        } else {
            // unexpected delim means empty token
            token = null;
        }
    }
    name=token;
    expectDelim = true;
               }

           expectDelim = false;
             while (tk3.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = tk3.nextToken();

    if (delim.equals(token)) {
         if (expectDelim) {
            expectDelim = false;
            continue;
        } else {
            // unexpected delim means empty token
            token = null;
        }
    }
    id=token;
    expectDelim = true;
               }
        expectDelim = false;
             while (tk4.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = tk4.nextToken();

    if (delim.equals(token)) {
         if (expectDelim) {
            expectDelim = false;
            continue;
        } else {
            // unexpected delim means empty token
            token = null;
        }
    }
    name1=token;
    expectDelim = true;
               }
            expectDelim = false;
             while (tk5.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = tk5.nextToken();

    if (delim.equals(token)) {
         if (expectDelim) {
            expectDelim = false;
            continue;
        } else {
            // unexpected delim means empty token
            token = null;
        }
    }
    id1=token;
    expectDelim = true;
               }

%>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="deals.php">Deals</a></li>
            </ul>
            <h3 class="text-muted">Admin List</h3>
        </div>


                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
                    Welcome user: Admin
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <br><br>


        <div class="row">


            <div class="col-md-12">
                            <table border="2" width="50%" align="center">
                                <tr><td>IPHONE</td> <td><a href='adminlist.jsp?id=<%=id%>' >EDIT</a></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Watch</td> <td><a href='adminlist.jsp?id=<%=id1%>' >EDIT</a></td></tr>

                            </table>
            </div>


            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <br><br>



        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
</body></html>
```

Error trace:

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.William2.web.index_jsp

type Exception report

message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.William2.web.index_jsp

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.William2.web.index_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:177)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.William2.web.index_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu) logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
```

Or:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [/var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp/William2/web/index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.json.simple.JSONValue resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file: [/var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp/William2/web/index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.json.JSONObject resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [16] in the generated java file: [/var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp/William2/web/index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.json.JSONArray resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [17] in the generated java file: [/var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp/William2/web/index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.json.JSONException resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [18] in the generated java file: [/var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp/William2/web/index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.json.JSONArray resolves to a package

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu) logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: Post your error trace.

Comment: do you have the Jar file for org.json and any other needed Jars on your web-inf/lib?

Comment: Have you added the JAR file to the WEB-INF/lib directory or you might have included the wrong JAR file. Check the JAR file that it contains the correct package or not. You can view the content of JAR file with WinRar or jd-gui.

Comment: WEB_INF contains web.xml http://pastebin.com/rSdqfcAa

Comment: Is import correct? org.json.simple.JSONValue resolves to a package